# Adding machine learning classifier at the end of CNN layer

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, keras, scikit-learn

I wanted to use the CNN as feature extractor for my images and then fed these features to some machine learning classifiers such as SVM, decision tree and KNN.
However when I was trying with SVM I got this error message:

**File "C:\Users\Afef-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 521, in _validate_targets
    " class" % len(cls))
ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class**

This is my code :

```
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from plot_metrics import plot_accuracy, plot_loss, plot_roc_curve
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
np.random.seed(15)  


"""
Using Theano backend and Theano image_dim_ordering:
(# channels, # images, # rows, # cols)
(1, 3040, 513, 125)
"""

def preprocess(X_train, X_test):
    """
    Convert from float64 to float32 and normalize normalize to decibels
    relative to full scale (dBFS) for the 4 sec clip.
    """
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

    X_train = np.array([(X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min()) for X in X_train])
    X_test = np.array([(X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min()) for X in X_test])
    return X_train, X_test


def prep_train_test(X_train, y_train1, X_test, y_test1, nb_classes):
    """
    Prep samples ands labels for Keras input by noramalzing and converting
    labels to a categorical representation.
    """
    print('Train on {} samples, validate on {}'.format(X_train.shape[0],
                                                       X_test.shape[0]))

    # normalize to dBfS
    X_train, X_test = preprocess(X_train, X_test)

    # Convert class vectors to binary class matrices
    Y_train1 = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
    Y_test1 = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

    return X_train, X_test, Y_train1, Y_test1


def keras_img_prep(X_train, X_test, img_dep, img_rows, img_cols):
    """
    Reshape feature matrices for Keras' expexcted input dimensions.
    For 'th' (Theano) dim_order, the model expects dimensions:
    (# channels, # images, # rows, # cols).
    """
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
        X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
        input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
    else:
        X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
        X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
        input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    return X_train, X_test, input_shape


def cnn(X_train, y_train1, X_test, y_test1, batch_size,
        nb_classes, epochs, input_shape):
    """
    The Convolutional Neural Net architecture for classifying the audio clips
    as normal (0) or depressed (1).
    """
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=1,
                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 3), strides=(1, 3)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), padding='valid', strides=1,
              input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 3), strides=(1, 3)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adadelta',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train1, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                        verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test1))


    # Evaluate accuracy on test and train sets
    score_train = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train1, verbose=0)
    print('Train accuracy:', score_train[1])
    score_test = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test1, verbose=0)
    print('Test accuracy:', score_test[1])
#    print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
    return model, history



if __name__ == '__main__':


    print('Retrieving locally')
    X_train = np.load('E:/depression detection/data/processed/train_samples.npz')
    y_train = np.load('E:/depression detection/data/processed/train_labels.npz')
    X_test = np.load('E:/depression detection/data/processed/test_samples.npz')
    y_test = np.load('E:/depression detection/data/processed/test_labels.npz')

    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = \
        X_train['arr_0'], y_train['arr_0'], X_test['arr_0'], y_test['arr_0']

    # CNN parameters
    batch_size = 32
    nb_classes = 2
    epochs = 7

    # normalalize data and prep for Keras
    print('Processing images for Keras...')
    X_train, X_test, y_train1, y_test1 = prep_train_test(X_train, y_train,
                                                       X_test, y_test,
                                                       nb_classes=nb_classes)

    # 513x125x1 for spectrogram with crop size of 125 pixels
    img_rows, img_cols, img_depth = X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1

    # reshape image input for Keras
    # used Theano dim_ordering (th), (# chans, # images, # rows, # cols)
    X_train, X_test, input_shape = keras_img_prep(X_train, X_test, img_depth,
                                                  img_rows, img_cols)


    # run CNN
    print('Fitting model...')
    model, history = cnn(X_train, y_train1, X_test, y_test1, batch_size,
                         nb_classes, epochs, input_shape)



    for l in range(len(model.layers)):
      print(l, model.layers[l])

     # feature extraction layer
    getFeature = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                       [model.layers[7].output])
# classification layer
    getPrediction = K.function([model.layers[8].input, K.learning_phase()],
                           [model.layers[9].output])

    exTrain = getFeature([X_train[:30], 0])[0]
    exTest = getFeature([X_test[:30], 0])[0]
    y_train00 = y_train[:30]
    y_test00 = y_test[:30]
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    clf = SVC(gamma='auto')
    clf.fit(exTrain, y_train00)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check y_test[:30] contains more than one class.

Comment: Ok,  I have checked and I found that it contains only one class. So I think I should add more input for the train and test. I Hope it works !!

Comment: That is the issue, to classify you need more than one category/class.

Comment: Yes, but i thought it was a problem of shape .The  inputs shape of SVM classifier are : exTrain.shape: (30, 512), exTest.shape: (30, 512), y_train00.shape : (30,) and  y_test00.shape) :(30,). The  inputs shape of CNN are :  X_train.shape: (2480, 1, 513, 125), X_test.shape: (560, 1, 513, 125) , y_train1.shape :  (2480, 2) and  y_test1.shape) :(560, 2)

Comment: can you please explain the comment. i didn't mention shape issue, number of categories is 1 which means first 30 values are from same class( y_test[:30]).
if you have classes A and B,  y_test[:30] is giving you all 30 A values. so there is no B class for the classifier to classify